# C# проект Avalonia: готовый проект не запускается под Linux

Tags: c#, linux, avalonia

MS Visual Studio 2019 Professional, установил пакет Avalonia, скомпилировал пробное  приложение, которое по идее должно быть кросс-платформенным (!) Оно без проблем запускается под Windows, но не хочет запускаться под Linux (Astra Linux CE, текущая). А именно - появляется окно с предложение выбрать программу, с помощью которой открыть exe.

Comment: а дотнеты там установлены, на линуксах?

Comment: кросплатформенный тут фреймворк, а не приложение. Само приложение запускается только там, где есть фреймворк.

Comment: [Building Avalonia](http://avaloniaui.net/contributing/build)

Comment: Пока не установлен, по-моему. Но думал, что это поставляется в дистрибутивах.

Comment: Каких дистрибутивах? Вы же сами приложение скомпилировали под виндой, то есть вы автор вашего приложения.

Comment: Приложения неткора надо явно публиковать под платформу, чтобы компилировался не exe файл. Например `dotnet publish my.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=AnyCPU /p:TargetFramework=netcoreapp2.1 /p:PublishDir=bin\Publish\netcoreapp2.1\linux-x64\ /p:SelfContained=true /p:RuntimeIdentifier=linux-x64` и дальше запускать файл одноименный названию проекта. На линуксе для этого потребуется установить ему права на запуск, разберетесь.

Comment: И да, при такой публикации (c `SelfContained=true`) никакой дотнет ставить не нужно.

Comment: Насколько я помню, астра - не обычный дистрибутив линукса. Там много чего менялось и авалонию даже подтачивали под Астру.  Возможно проблема в этом. 
Вообще запуск dotnet run <uapp.dll> должно работать. Если нет - гуглите эту проблему под свой дистрибутив!

Comment: @Monk, попробовал сделать как Вы написали, дал права, линукс пишет: ошибка формата исполняемого файла. А запуск через дотнет работает (dotnet project.dll). Я что-то не так сделал, или все же ставить дотнет необходимо? Может нужно еще какую-то директиву дать, чтобы компилятор нативный код сделал?

Comment: @JohnnyRage подтверждаю что Авалония работает на Астре (Орел). мой hello world по крайней мере запустился без проблем

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте установить https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download
или https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

После установки пробуйте

```
dotnet application.exe
```

или

```
mono application.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `chmod +x ИмяФайла`, запуск через `./ИмяФайла`